# What field type is the Set Timer field on the Blackberry?

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry, field

I'm writing an application which has an interval time as a parameter and would like a field similar to the one the Timer has to set its time. Values of a few seconds to a few hours make sense for the application.

What type of field should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a custom field.

Your choices with built-in fields are:
   `net.rim.device.api.ui.component.NumericChoiceField`, which basically acts like a drop-down with numbers in it (not great when you're talking about 60 minutes/seconds, but if you want to constrain to say 5 minute intervals or something it might be ok).

`net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField` with a custom `net.rim.device.api.ui.text.TextFilter` (you could use a `NumericTextFilter`, but that wouldn't constrain you to 0-60, it'd allow any numbers).

Or you can roll you own.  See [this article](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/167) for a start on creating custom fields.  You'll probably want to override `navigationMovement` to make the numbers increment/decrement on trackball up & down, and to move the focus within the field while going left & right - setting an internal state variable indicating where the focus is and overriding `getFocusRect` to return an appropriate focus rectangle (be sure to call `focusRemove` and `focusAdd` from within `navigationMovement` to let the framework know you've updated the focus).

Comment: Yeah, my backup plan is an EditField with a NumericTextFilter. This is for an assignment and were told to spend little time on the GUI, so rolling my own custom field is more work than I'd like. Oh well.